# Gunicorn doesn't create MyProject.sock file

Tags: ubuntu, socket

I'm not a Unix expert and I'm having a problem with a WebApp running on Azure on an Ubuntu server (20.04.5 LTS), gunicorn.service doesn't create the MyProjet.sock file.
Specific, the WebApp has always worked, from one day to the next the MyProject.sock file was deleted and I can't recreate it.

I tried following several solutions found here and on StackOverflow, more precisely this sequence of commands

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx 
sudo systemctl stop gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

The result I get is the following

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-01-12 13:40:11 UTC; 1min 18s ago
    Process: 2305577 ExecStart=/home/admin/myproject/backend/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout 1800 --bind unix:/home/admin/myproject/backend/myproject.sock project.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 2305577 (code=exited, status=3)

Jan 12 13:40:10 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305583]: Inner error: {
Jan 12 13:40:10 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305583]:     "code": "ForbiddenByFirewall"
Jan 12 13:40:10 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305583]: }
Jan 12 13:40:10 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305583]: [2024-01-12 13:40:10 +0000] [2305583] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2305583)
Jan 12 13:40:11 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305577]: [2024-01-12 13:40:11 +0000] [2305577] [WARNING] Worker with pid 2305584 was terminated due to signal 15
Jan 12 13:40:11 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305577]: [2024-01-12 13:40:11 +0000] [2305577] [WARNING] Worker with pid 2305583 was terminated due to signal 15
Jan 12 13:40:11 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305577]: [2024-01-12 13:40:11 +0000] [2305577] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Jan 12 13:40:11 DeployUbuntu gunicorn[2305577]: [2024-01-12 13:40:11 +0000] [2305577] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Jan 12 13:40:11 DeployUbuntu systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Jan 12 13:40:11 DeployUbuntu systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I noticed that if I try to execute the commands all at once by concatenating them instead the service seems to work

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx && sudo systemctl stop gunicorn.service && sudo systemctl restart nginx && sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.service && sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-01-12 13:40:10 UTC; 22ms ago
   Main PID: 2305577 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9530)
     Memory: 2.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             └─2305577 /home/admin/myproject/backend/venv/bin/python /home/admin/myproject/backend/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout 1800 --bind unix:/home/admin/myproject/backend/myproject.sock project.wsgi>
Jan 12 13:40:10 DeployUbuntu systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
```

But if I immediately execute

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

It gives me the error message I indicated above.

In my **gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=admin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/myproject/backend
ExecStart=/home/admin/myproject/backend/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout 1800 --bind unix:/home/admin/myproject/backend/myproject.sock project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would add that I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling both gunicorn and the project.
Lastly, I would like to add that the version of gunicorn used is 20.1.0, this is due to the project specifications.

Comment: You are trying to bind to a Unix socket. Try binding to a TCP socket instead.

Comment: I didn't create the binding, it was created that way and it worked perfectly until 2 weeks ago, then the myproject.sock file was deleted. My problem is recreating that file. I don't understand if there are problems with the firewall or something else that is preventing it from being created.

Comment: `code": "ForbiddenByFirewall`: Is the port that gunicorn uses blocked at the moment? Try poking a hole in your firewall and report back.